# Error using OS module with raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I have wrote the following code:

```
import os

def a():
    take = raw_input("insert: ")
    os.system("ifconfig eth0 hw ether %d") %take

a()
```

i get an error that `unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'`.
how can i make it work and get the string from 'take' that will be with letters, numbers and punctuation..?? (i want to insert a MAC address..).

Thannks

Comment: Fix the format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `raw_input` returns a string so the variable `take` is a string.

```
import os

def a():
   take = raw_input("insert: ")
   os.system("ifconfig eth0 hw ether %s" % take)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect Try below code

```
os.system("ifconfig eth0 hw ether %d"%take)
```

Use this :

```
import os

def a():
   take = raw_input("insert: ")
   os.system("ifconfig eth0 hw ether %s" % take)
```